# Entity Framework v4 -> need some help with POCO's and Entities

Tags: c#, .net, poco, entities

I'm using EF4 and I've got two entities that I wish to map to the *same* `POCO`. I'm not sure how I can do this.

> Entity 1 → Foo (this represents a table FOO in the db)
>   POCO → Foo
>
> Entity 2 → FooView (this represents a view FooView in the db)
>   POCO → Foo

I understand that I need to do something like

```
IObjectSet<Foo> _foos = CreateObjectSet<Foo>();

// Note spelling of the Entity.
IObjectSet<Foo> _foosView = CreateObjectSet<Foo>("FooViews");
```

But when i try this, it does compile, but it fails with the following exception:

> System.ArgumentException: 
>       System.ArgumentException: The specified entity type, 'MyProject.Core.Foo', 
>       does not match the type 'EntityFramework.SqlServerModel.FoosView'
>       from the EntitySet 'FoosViews'.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [How to: Define a Model with Multiple Entity Sets per Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738537(VS.100,lightweight).aspx)
- [How to: Add an Object to a Specific Entity Set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738691(VS.100,lightweight).aspx)

Here is a checklist of things to look for:

1. Your **Storage Model** should have:

   1. Two `EntitySets`: `Foo` and `FooView`
   2. Two `EntityTypes`: `Foo` and `FooView`
2. Your **Conceptual Model** should have:

   1. Two `EntitySets`: `Foo` and `FooView` - **both** with an `EntityType` set to `ModelName.Foo`
   2. One `EntityType`: `Foo`
3. Your **Mapping** should have two `EntitySetMappings`:

   1. `Foo` with one `EntityTypeMapping` ("ModelName.Foo") with one `MappingFragment` ("Foo")
   2. `FooView` with one `EntityTypeMapping` ("ModelName.**Foo**") with one `MappingFragment` ("FooView")

You should new be able to execute the following:

```
Foo foo = new ModelEntities()
    .CreateObjectSet<Foo>("FooView")
    .First();
```

You can give yourself a headstart by doing the following:

1. Add `Foo` and `FooView` to your model
2. In the `Mapping Details` of `Foo` click `Add a Table or View` and select `FooView`
3. Delete `FooView` from your model
4. Save the model and open it in the XML editor
5. *([pre-RTM](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adonetefx/thread/5c70420d-ec7b-400c-a05b-f1bb17ab4590))* Find `<EntityType Name="FooView">` in `<StorageModels>` and remove any incorrect entries from `<Key>` (it should match `<EntityType Name="Foo">`)
6. Remove the `<EntityTypeMapping Name="IsTypeOf(Foo)" />` and `<EntityTypeMapping Name="IsTypeOf(FooView)" />` (they caused me errors)

***As of beta 2, implementing the above will break the designer***

Comment: Hi Richard - thanks heaps for this post. There's a lot of data here so i'll try and work through this as quickly as possible before the time runs out. In your first step, are you saying that i create TWO poco's - one called `Foo` and the other `FooView` ? Also, when your post talks about `entity types`, is this what i refer to as my POCO class? and `multiple entity sets`, this means my *tables* that are on my designer (eg. table Foo and view FooView) ?

Comment: In my examples I wasn't using POCOs, but the concept is the same. The main thing is to keep two separate entity sets, and two different **storage** EntityTypes but one only **conceptual** EntityType.

Comment: Also conceptual EntityTypes are the same as your POCOs. Storage EntityTypes are the representation of the database table.

Comment: Richad, I can't get past step two because of a bug in EF4 Beta2 (rumour has it that it's fixed in RTM: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adonetefx/thread/5c70420d-ec7b-400c-a05b-f1bb17ab4590) That said, if i change the xml file, will this then get reset if i refresh/update the designer from the DB?

Comment: Just continue past step 2 anyway (you'll see that key problem is covered in step 5). No, I think you have to explicitly request it to update the view.

Comment: Ok - so far so good. I followed all the steps and it compiles. Now, i'm not sure how to generate an object that now references `FooView`. I mean, my `Foo` EntityModel now maps to two things -> `(table) Foo` and `(View) FooView`. So how does this last step work? At first i thought it was `IObjectSet<Foo> fooViews = CreateObjectSet<Foo>("FooView")` but that doesn't work because in the 3rd step, we removed the Entity `FooView` from the EF Model. And the Entity `Foo` now has TWO (database) mappings .. so how does it know which one to use/reference?

Comment: There should be two (storage) entity sets defined in your entity model (open it as XML), so you should be able to use `CreateObjectSet<Foo>("FooView")`

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too. I do have two entity models -> http://i46.tinypic.com/2hrh92a.png Foo = LogEntries, FooView = ConnectedPlayersView ... but I still get the exception: `System.InvalidOperationException: The EntitySet name 'Entities.FooView' could not be found.`

Comment: You should also have two Entity *Sets* defined. It's possible you'll need to add it manually.

Comment: Yep, i have those two sets already in here.... http://i45.tinypic.com/30m5pv7.png  Could it be a Namespace issue, in the string argument which I ass into the static method `CreateObjectSet<LogEntry>(..)` ?

Comment: Ok, I now have a working (including runtime) example. See my update above.

Comment: Ahh. i was missing `FooView` from the conceptual model. Besides hardcoding that into the conceptual model, how does it normally get there? when i drop thew view onto the designer? because if so, i thought i had to delete `FooView` from the designer AFTER i did the mapping... ??? (step 3). When that happens I think it is removed from the conceptual model.... ???

Comment: Also, this is a screenie of my Conceptual model. i just don't understand your Update Step #2.... http://i49.tinypic.com/2mm8tu9.png

Comment: Awesome :) works! Bummer that the designer doesn't work any more :( Not sure why that is.... Is that the same for you, Richard? (`ala: Warning ; Error 11003: Entity type 'LogEntry (Foo)' exists in multiple entity sets: LogEntries (Foos) , ConnectedPlayersView (FoosView).`)

Comment: I get the same warning. Hopefully that limitation is fixed in the RTM

Comment: Cheers Richard for working with me to solve this issue. I sincerly appreciate it. Thanks kindly!

Answer (score 1):

In NHibernate, one should solve this using Projections.
So, I think that there must exists something similar like that in the Entity Framework.  I've googled a bit, and I came accross this:

- [Object Queries (Entity Framework)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896241.aspx)